# Finding growth Function

Tags: c++, time-complexity, big-o

I'm trying to find growth function of given code.

```
int sum = 0; 
 for (int k = n; k > 0; k /= 2)  {
    cout<<k<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) 
    {
        sum++; 
        cout<<i<<endl;
    }
 }
```

but I'm stuck in first loop for `(int k = n; k > 0; k /= 2)` , it's being execute in this way :

```
for n = 5 , it executes 3 times
n = 10 , 4 times
n = 100 , 7 times
n = 1000 , 10 times
```

how can I generalize it?

Comment: Hint: Instead of using powers of 10 (10, 100, 1000) try using powers of 2 and see if you notice a clearer pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, 10 is about log_2 of 1000. There are about log_2(n) iterations of the outer loop. However, that doesn't tell you the total number of steps because you do a variable number of steps inside.

n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ... = 2n = O(n). You are doing a constant number of things inside the loops, so the total number of steps is O(n). About half of the time is spent on the first iteration of the outer loop, when k=n.

Answer (score 3):

At each step `k` is divided by two, cut in halves. How many cuts do you need to go to zero?

After 1 cut you have `n/2`.
After 2 cuts you have `n/4`.
After 3 cuts you have `n/8`.
After 4 cuts you have `n/16`.
After 5 cuts you have `n/32`.
After `x` cuts you have `n/2x`.

So, how long until `n = 2x`?
Answer is simple: `x = log2(n)`.

Your loop runs at `log n` times.

But the inner loop runs on the size of these parts. The first run is of size `n`, the second is `n/2`, the third is `n/4` and so on. The sum of all runs of this inner loop is:

`n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ... = 2n`.

Thus the total run time equals `O(n)` (thanks Douglas Zare!)